# Error al Importar Paquete 'google.colab' en Python (Subir y Descargar Archivos PC local y Google Drive)

Tags: python, google-colab

He leido la documentacion de google colab acerca de la subida y descarga de archvios. Encontré esto:

https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb?hl=es#scrollTo=c2W5A2px3doP
Puedes acceder a los archivos alojados en Drive de diversas maneras, como las siguientes:

> Activar tu Google Drive en la máquina virtual del entorno de ejecución
> Usar un envoltorio en la API, como PyDrive
> Usando la API REST nativa

,pero al instalar el paquete google-colab en pycharm(Windows) e importar: `from google.colab import files`
me da error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Victor
Lerlin/PycharmProjects/adivinaproject/main.py", line 60, in <module>
    from google.colab import files   File "C:\Users\Victor Lerlin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\google\colab\__init__.py",
line 23, in <module>
    from google.colab import _system_commands   File "C:\Users\Victor Lerlin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\google\colab\_system_commands.py",
line 24, in <module>
    import pty   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pty.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tty   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tty.py", line 5, in <module>
    from termios import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios'
```

Alguien tiene idea del Error?, Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Hola victorcedronayala! El error es claro, te dice que no tienes instalado el paquete `termios` por tanto no puedes importarlo

Comment: El método que te describe ese colab para acceder a tus archivos de Drive, en principio sólo funciona desde dentro del propio google colab. En el fondo se limita a montar como carpeta (en /contents/drive/MyDrive) tu espacio de Google Drive. No creo que una cosa así funcione en windows porque no puedes montar carpetas. Lo que supongo que puedes hacer en Windows (y esto es independiente de Python, Jupyter o Spyder) es instalar un cliente de GDrive para que en tu disco aparezca una copia de lo que tengas en drive, sincronizada con él (algo como lo que hace dropbox)

Comment: @abulafia Muchas Gracias